# pivot_longer repeat entries instead of counting them

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to use `pivot_longer` to create a datatable which is easy to visualize.
The code I am using looks something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

relig_income %>%
  pivot_longer(!religion, names_to = "income", values_to = "count")
```

The output looks like this (not really, I changed the `count` column):

```r
   religion income             count
   <chr>    <chr>              <dbl>
 1 Agnostic <$10k                 3
 2 Agnostic $10-20k               2
   ....
```

However, for my purposes, it would be much more useful if the output would look like this:

```
   religion income             
   <chr>    <chr>              
 1 Agnostic <$10k                
 2 Agnostic <$10k                
 3 Agnostic <$10k                
 4 Agnostic $10-20k               
 5 Agnostic $10-20k               
   ...
```

So, basically, in the end there should only be two columns left and the `income` column should just repeat the specific value as often as the entry in the `count` column.
Is there an option within `pivot_longer` or another R function which conveniently transforms the dataframe?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `relig_income` is an example dataset provided by the `tidyverse` package. I have edited my question.

Comment: Sorry. My bad!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do `uncount` From package tidyr:

```
library(tidyverse)

relig_income %>%
  pivot_longer(!religion, names_to = "income", values_to = "count") %>%
  uncount(count)

# A tibble: 35,556 x 2
   religion income
   <chr>    <chr> 
 1 Agnostic <$10k 
 2 Agnostic <$10k 
 3 Agnostic <$10k 
 4 Agnostic <$10k 
 5 Agnostic <$10k 
 6 Agnostic <$10k 
 7 Agnostic <$10k 
 8 Agnostic <$10k 
 9 Agnostic <$10k 
10 Agnostic <$10k 
# ... with 35,546 more rows
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `group_by` `religion` and `income`, which contains the specific combination that you would like to expand. Then `rep` each row with the values in `count`. Finally remove the `count` column.

```
library(tidyverse)

relig_income %>%
  pivot_longer(!religion, names_to = "income", values_to = "count") %>% 
  group_by(religion, income) %>% 
  slice(rep(1:n(), each = count)) %>% 
  select(-count)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much. Produces exactly what I want.